# How to set and get tag in xaml dynamically?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

While creating GUI using xaml, I created a textbox with a tag like this:

```
<TextBox Name="TextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="216,178,143,120" Width="158"
             Tag="myTag"/>
```

Now I want to let the user be able to change this tag. For that, I am looking for a kind of function of form:

```
TextBox.SetTag( "User Provided Tag" )
```

So that the tag can be changed into this one:

```
<TextBox Name="TextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="216,178,143,120" Width="158"
             Tag="User Provided Tag"/>
```

After searching the internet for quite a while, I didn't come up with any practical solution. Could someone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a binding between two controls. Say a user is allowed to enter a tag value from a `TextBox`. You just bind the `Tag` of the second `TextBox` to a `Text` property of the first `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox Name="enterTagTextBox" />
<TextBox Name="getTagTextBox" Tag="{Binding ElementName=enterTagTextBox, Path=Text}"/>
```

To test it I added a `Button` in my XAML:

```
<Button Height="25" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
```

In code behind I just retrieve the tag value and display it like this:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string text = this.getTagTextBox.Tag.ToString();
    global::System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(text);
}
```

Comment: I did it as you suggested, but after entering some text to 'enterTagTextBox' in the GUI, then displayed the tag of "getTagTextBox" in a messageBox but it is blank. My way of displaying the tag is this:    MessageBox.Show( getTagTextBox.Tag.toString());   I was expecting to see my entered text

Comment: Ok, the problem is this: by using your code, when I entered a text to 'enterTagTextBox', it gives me blank result. But when I entered a text to 'getTagTextBox', it gives me my entered string. What is the reason?

Comment: I want to set the tag in 'enterTagTextBox', not in 'getTagTextBox', but it is working reversely now.

Comment: I added my steps to test it to the answer

Comment: Check the binding in `getTagTextBox`, make sure the `ElementName` is set to the proper `TextBox` that is to `enterTagTextBox`

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem may arise from you naming your TextBox, "TextBox". Try giving it a name that does not clash with the class name, like "txtMyTextBox".

Then you can do, `txtMyTextBox.Tag = "User Provided Tag";`.

Or you can bind to it as PiotrWolkowski suggests.

However, I would like to add, that it seems like there should be a cleaner way of achieving your desired behaviour. With the caveat that I don't know the details of what you are trying to implement.

I strongly suggest creating a ViewModel (see: [MVVM Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel)) to hold the data you want users to be able to edit. Then use the bindings in WPF to display the data.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use the property element usage in order to set the Tag property in Extensible Application Markup Language (XAML) to anything other than an object with a known and built-in type converter, such as a string.